# Fail on checking var_dump condition

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a file list, but when I use my code, my sentence doesn't work. Here's my code:

```
<?php 
$dir = "C:\wamp\www";
$scan = scandir($dir);
print_r ($scan);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($scan); $i++){

    if (TRUE == var_dump(is_dir($scan[$i]))) {
        print ("hi");
    }
    else {
        print ("ho");
    }};
?>
```

This only returns "ho" https://gyazo.com/36408b7866ff368ef6f898161ea06c88

Comment: Remove the `var_dump` and just do: `if (is_dir($scan[$i]))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you check var_dump oficial documentation, this function returns void.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

You usually use var_dump for debugging or inspecting process. You should do in your condition only:

```
if (is_dir($scan[$i])) {
        print ("hi");
    }
    else {
        print ("ho");
    }};
```

which returns true or false according to oficial documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php

Comment: @ithan please select best answer please.

Answer (score 0):

var_dump returns **void**.
And *void* never can be equal to **TRUE**

... like Randall Valenciano has said before.